# Error: Compile Error: No such column 'color__c' on entity 'Product2'

Tags: trigger

```
trigger oppLineTrigger on OpportunityLineItem (before insert) {
// For every OpportunityLineItem record, add its associated pricebook entry
// to a set so there are no duplicates.
Set<Id> pbeIds = new Set<Id>();
  for (OpportunityLineItem oli : Trigger.new)
  pbeIds.add(oli.pricebookentryid);
  // Query the PricebookEntries for their associated product color and place the //results in a map.
Map<Id, PricebookEntry> entries = new Map<Id, PricebookEntry>(
  [select Product2.color__c from PricebookEntry where id in :pbeIds]);
  // Now use the map to set the appropriate color on every OpportunityLineItem processed by the trigger.
  for (OpportunityLineItem oli : Trigger.new)
  oli.color__c = entries.get(oli.pricebookEntryId).product2.color__c;
}
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere? Simply throwing up code and expecting others to be able to infer the question will not get you many responses. Ask a question like you would expect someone to ask it to you. If I just shoved a piece of paper in front of you and said nothing would you know what I was trying to say? The title here helps but the more time you spend crafting the question, the more time people will spend helping you to resolve the issue.

Comment: Sounds like he is working through the Apex Dev Guide and got hung up with the example.  Pg 210-211           "Using Maps and Sets in Bulk Triggers"  https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self explanatory:

There is no field with the API nome on the Product Object.

Click Setup -> Customize -> Products -> Fields

An you will see the list of custom fields. Click on the field you think is Color__c and Check the API name.

Also, do not confuse the Product2 with the Opportunity Products. Not the same objects.